# Centos can't execute scripts anymore...'unable to execute... permission denied'

Tags: centos

We are running
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009

Something changed in the last day or two that I can't execute a bin file. I downloaded the file directly from the website.

```
file atlassian-confluence-7.4.7-x64.bin
atlassian-confluence-7.4.7-x64.bin: data
```

I try

```
chmod a+x atlassian-confluence-7.4.7-x64.bin
```

file has permissions
-rwxrwxr-x.

and then try to run

```
sudo ./atlassian-confluence-7.4.7-x64.bin
sudo: unable to execute ./atlassian-confluence-7.4.7-x64.bin: Permission denied
```

What has happened that I can't even execute a bin file anymore.
Appreciate any suggestions...
Thanks!

Note: I also just checked and I get permission denied if I even create a little 'echo hello' shell script.

```
ls -lah /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x. 1 root root 144K Jan 26 21:56 /usr/bin/sudo
```

```
 ls -lah /etc/sudoers
-r--r-----. 1 root root 4.5K Sep 26  2019 /etc/sudoers
```

The same file on a difference linux box

```
file atlassian-confluence-7.4.7-x64.bin
atlassian-confluence-7.4.7-x64.bin: POSIX shell script executable (binary data)
```

Comment: What are the permissions of `/etc/sudoers` and `/usr/bin/sudo`?

Comment: If `file` reports `data` instead of `shell script` or `ELF`, I would assume that this is indeed not code. Perhaps you downloaded an executable for a different architecture, or the file was corrupted. Can you share the `echo hello` script and how you execute it? Are there other binaries that fail like that?

Comment: The permissions look correct, try running this command your username should be in the output. `cat /etc/group | grep wheel` If your username is not in the output you have somehow have had your sudo privileges removed.  If this is the case you will have to add your user to the wheel group and then reboot.

Comment: I tried to answer the questions up above, thank you so much for the suggestions... hah, I'm not sure what I did.  And I do appear to still be a member of the wheel group.

Comment: When you say the file has permissions `-rwxrwxr-x.` does that INCLUDE THE DOT? If so and your system has SELinux turned on ('enforcing') check the SELinux context with `ls -Z`.